# Why are questions sometimes deleted by moderators?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

This question: [Where can I find a vertical menu like google?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7423250/561731) seemed perfectly legit, and It has a few good answers.

Why was it deleted?

<sup>Sorry if you do not enough rep to view the deleted question</sup>

Comment: Maybe he was on an anti-"Give me teh codez" rampage?

Comment: Judging from the title, it is not a perfectly legit question...we're a problem-solving-community and not a search-machine.

Comment: @Straitjacked - should we be voting to close/flagging all of these style questions? They come up *alot* and usually get answered with no votes from what I've seen. I just ignore them unless they're in a tag I read a lot (but they're rarer in those)

Comment: @awoodland: Yes, they fall under the downvote-category `shows little research effort` and most of the time people didn't even *try* before asking. Additionally they add very little value as the 'answers' are temporary and can change within days. And they of course do not have a definitive answer. But there are exceptions, but you normally recognize them very easily and would never think about downvoting them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Because they completely fail to reach even the lowest imaginable quality bar.
2. Because they are egregiously off-topic per the FAQ
3. Because they were flagged, downvoted, etc by the community
4. Because the presence of this question is a broken window, implying that we tolerate extremely low quality content on our sites
5. Because we trust moderators to make decisions that protect and uphold the quality of their communities

Answer (score 15):

It shows little research, no concrete problem besides "show me the code". Basically, it really doesn't have much value: I voted to close as **Too Localized** (although *Not Constructive* would have been good too). Jeff just beat the 4 other people needed to close it to the punch.

Comment: I see nothing that @Jeff voted to close, i just see that he **deleted it**. Should it not have been closed by the community 1st? Then someone could delete to their heart's content.

Comment: Err, I guess I'll elaborate: I was the vote to close! Jeff just came in and realized it didn't need to wait for 4 more.

Comment: ok, so why did he not put his 2 cents in and **vote to close**? instead he just blatantly deleted the question!

Comment: @Neal: Because he's the boss and a moderator. He can make those decisions.

Comment: @0A0D -- It is supposed to be *community run*, not a dictatorship.

Comment: A moderator's *2 cents* is binding. If they feel it should be deleted, then *poof*. If I was in a position to do so, I'd have deleted as well. But I'm not put in positions where I can do these things, because I'd do lots of *poof*.

Comment: @Neal: I imagine him, stuck at home with the new baby, silently going crazy until he says to himself, "I *have* to delete something."  And then he goes and deletes something and is okay for another few hours.

Comment: @Neal: This is not some sh¡††y forum, it is a high quality Q&A site. We want good questions and answers, actually excellent.

Comment: @Won't: So that's why everyone changes their names on Meta...so that he can't lock his `delete-and-forget`-missiles on.

Comment: @StraitJacket - I never got the memo about that.... I have the same name on all SE sites.

Comment: @Neal: [Then here you go.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518)

Comment: @Neal: As far as I know, SE is community *driven*, that's a slight difference there. I also don't see how this relates to a dictation in any way. By the way...this is a dictation, we're just allowed to state our opinions and wishes, but the company (`stack exchange inc`) decides what's happening and what's going to happen.

Comment: I have no problem whatsoever with Jeff deleting obviously, clearly crap content. Quite the contrary, I think it's great one of the owners takes so much interest in the quality of the site. It's one of the reasons why I'm here.

Comment: @pekka - indeed...that question was....crap...wish I'd got there first.

Comment: @Strait wait, Won't is Will? What??

Comment: @Neal - the site IS community run/driven. And the community has by and large demonstrated that its perfectly happy for questions that don't so much to clear the quality bar as whack themselves in the head with it repeatedly to be closed and deleted as soon as reasonably possible.

Comment: @AakashM: welcome to the Matrix. ;P